# socket.shutdown vs socket.close

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous

I recently saw a bit of code that looked like this (with sock being a socket object of course):

```
sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
sock.close()
```

What exactly is the purpose of calling shutdown on the socket and then closing it?  If it makes a difference, this socket is being used for non-blocking IO.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here's one [explanation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.progcomm/doc/progcomc/skt_shutdn.htm):

> Once a socket is no longer required,
>   the calling program can discard the
>   socket by applying a close subroutine
>   to the socket descriptor. If a
>   reliable delivery socket has data
>   associated with it when a close takes
>   place, the system continues to attempt
>   data transfer. However, if the data is
>   still undelivered, the system discards
>   the data. Should the application
>   program have no use for any pending
>   data, it can use the shutdown
>   subroutine on the socket prior to
>   closing it.

Answer (score 307):

Calling `close` and `shutdown` have two different effects on the underlying socket.

The first thing to point out is that the socket is a resource in the underlying OS and **multiple processes can have a handle for the same underlying socket.**

When you call `close` it decrements the handle count by one and if the handle count has reached zero then the socket and associated connection goes through the normal close procedure (effectively sending a FIN / EOF to the peer) and the socket is deallocated.

The thing to pay attention to here is that if the handle count does not reach zero because another process still has a handle to the socket then the connection **is not closed and the socket is not deallocated.**

On the other hand calling `shutdown` for reading and writing closes the underlying connection and sends a FIN / EOF to the peer regardless of how many processes have handles to the socket.  However, it **does not** deallocate the socket and you still need to call close afterward.

Comment: great answer, i never bothered to find out what `shutdown()` does :)

Comment: Can a shutdown() for read causes it to send a FIN packet? i.e. shutdown(sock_fd, 1);

Comment: Would it be smart to always call `.shutdown()` and on the next line `.close()`? Or should there be a delay in between?

Comment: @Luc Completely depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes I just want to get rid of the connection. Send a FIN and disallocate the RAM.

Comment: @Luc Then just close is fine as long as no other processes have a handle to the socket.

Answer (score 21):

Explanation of shutdown and close: [Graceful shutdown (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738547(VS.85).aspx)

Shutdown (in your case) indicates to the other end of the connection there is no further intention to read from or write to the socket. Then close frees up any memory associated with the socket.

Omitting shutdown may cause the socket to linger in the OSs stack until the connection has been closed gracefully.

IMO the names 'shutdown' and 'close' are misleading, 'close' and 'destroy' would emphasise their differences.

Comment: It does not indicate to the other end that there is no further intention to read. Shutdown for read doesn't send anything to the peer.

Answer (score 10):

it's mentioned right in the Socket Programming HOWTO ([py2](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#disconnecting)/[py3](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#disconnecting))

> **Disconnecting**
>
> Strictly speaking, you’re supposed to use `shutdown` on a socket before you `close` it.
>   The `shutdown` is an advisory to the socket at the other end. Depending on the argument you pass it, it can mean “*I’m not going to send anymore, but I’ll still listen*”, or “*I’m not listening, good riddance!*”.
>   Most socket libraries, however, are so used to programmers neglecting to use this piece of etiquette that normally a `close` is the same as `shutdown(); close()`.
>   So in most situations, an explicit shutdown is not needed.
>
> ...

Comment: This information isn't correct. It is only ever necessary to shutdown a socket for writing if (1) you have forked the process and definitely want to send the FIN *now,* or (2) you are engaging in a mutual read-to-EOS protocol such that both peers close at the same time. Otherwise `close()` is sufficient. The Python documentation should be corrected.

Comment: how can the other side detect if a shutdown was sent?

Answer (score 4):

Isn't this code above wrong?

The close call directly after the shutdown call might make the kernel discard all outgoing buffers anyway.

According to
http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable
one needs to wait between the shutdown and the close until read returns 0.

Comment: Not correct. The kernel will only discard outgoing buffers if the connection has been reset, which can happen if the local app hasn't read all the pending inbound data that has already arrived, or if the peer has messed with SO_LINGER, which they shouldn't do. There is no necessity to sleep either, nor even to call shutdown before close. There is a lot of misinformation out there about this matter.

Answer (score 3):

there are some flavours of shutdown: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.shutdown.aspx. *nix is similar.

Comment: There is one 'flavour' of shutdown, and it has two options, which can be combined. Nothing here answers the actual question.

Answer (score -1):

Shutdown(1) , forces the socket no to send any more data

This is usefull in

1- Buffer flushing

2- Strange error detection

3- Safe guarding

Let me explain more , when you send a data from A to B , it's not guaranteed to be 
sent to B , it's only guaranteed to be sent to the A os buffer , 
which in turn sends it to the B os buffer

So by calling shutdown(1) on A , you flush A's buffer and an error is raised 
if the buffer is not empty ie: data has not been sent to the peer yet

Howoever this is irrevesable , so you can do that after you completely 
sent all your data and you want to be sure that it's atleast at the peer 
os buffer

Comment: Shutdown does not force a flush. The buffering situation is unchanged. And if the buffer isn't empty no error is raised. The FIN is merely enqueued behind the pending data. Answer is completely incorrect.