# Java, server client TCP communication ends with RST

Tags: java, tcp

I'm trying to figure out if this is normal. Because without errors, a connection should be terminated by:

```
FIN ->
<- ACK
<- FIN
ACK ->
```

I get this at the end of a TCP connection (over SSL, but i also get it with non-encrypted):

```
         From     To
1494    server  client  TCP search-agent > 59185 [PSH, ACK] Seq=25974 Ack=49460 Win=63784 Len=50
1495    client  server  TCP 59185 > search-agent [ACK] Seq=49460 Ack=26024 Win=63565 Len=0
1496    client  server  TCP 59185 > search-agent [PSH, ACK] Seq=49460 Ack=26024 Win=63565 Len=23
1497    client  server  TCP 59185 > search-agent [FIN, ACK] Seq=49483 Ack=26024 Win=63565 Len=0
1498    server  client  TCP search-agent > 59185 [PSH, ACK] Seq=26024 Ack=49484 Win=63784 Len=23
1499    client  server  TCP 59185 > search-agent [RST, ACK] Seq=49484 Ack=26047 Win=0 Len=0
```

The client exits normally and reaches *socket.close*, shouldn't then the connection be shut down normally, without a reset?

I can't find anything about the TCP streams of java on google...

Here is my code:

Server:

```
package Security;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.net.ServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SSLDemoServer
{
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static final int PORT = 1234;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int received = 0;
        String returned; 
        ObjectInputStream input = null;
        PrintWriter output = null;
        Socket client;

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "key.keystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "vwpolo");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "key.keystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "vwpolo");

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Trying to set up server ...");
            ServerSocketFactory factory = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            serverSocket = factory.createServerSocket(PORT);

            System.out.println("Server started!\n");
        }
        catch (IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to set up port!");
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        while(true)
        {
            client = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client trying to connect...");

            try
            {
                System.out.println("Trying to create inputstream...");
                input = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("Trying to create outputstream...");
                output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                System.out.println("Client successfully connected!");

                while( true )
                {
                    received = input.readInt();
                    returned = Integer.toHexString(received);
                    System.out.print(" " + received);
                    output.println(returned.toUpperCase());
                }
            }
            catch(SSLException sslEx)
            {
                System.out.println("Connection failed! (non-SSL connection?)\n");
                client.close();
                continue;
            }
            catch(EOFException eofEx)
            {
                System.out.println("\nEnd of client data.\n");
            }
            catch(IOException ioEx)
            {
                System.out.println("I/O problem! (correct inputstream?)");
            }

            try {
                input.close();
                output.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
            client.close();
            System.out.println("Client closed.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
package Security;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

import java.util.*;

public class SSLDemoClient
{
    private static InetAddress host;
    private static final int PORT = 1234;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "key.keystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "vwpolo");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "key.keystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "vwpolo");

        System.out.println("\nCreating SSL socket ...");
        SSLSocket socket = null;
        try
        {
            host = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.56.101");
            SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)
            SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, PORT);
            socket.startHandshake();
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException uhEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nHost ID not found!\n");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(SSLException sslEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nHandshaking unsuccessful ...");
            System.exit(1);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("\nHandshaking succeeded ...\n");

        SSLClientThread client = new SSLClientThread(socket);
        SSLReceiverThread receiver = new SSLReceiverThread(socket);

        client.start();
        receiver.start();

        try
        {
            client.join();
            receiver.join();
            System.out.println("Trying to close...");
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException iEx)
        {
            iEx.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("\nClient finished.");
    }
}


class SSLClientThread extends Thread
{
    private SSLSocket socket;

    public SSLClientThread(SSLSocket s)
    {
        socket = s;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            for( int i = 1; i < 1025; i++)
            {
                output.writeInt(i);
                sleep(10);
                output.flush();
            } 

            output.flush();
            sleep(1000);
            output.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("Socket closed or unable to open socket.");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException iEx)
        {
            iEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


class SSLReceiverThread extends Thread
{
    private SSLSocket socket;

    public SSLReceiverThread(SSLSocket s)
    {
        socket = s;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String response = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;

        try
        {
            input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            try
            {
                response = input.readLine();
                while(!response.equals(null)) 
                {
                    System.out.print(response + " ");
                    response = input.readLine();
                } 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("\nEnd of server data.\n");
            }    

            input.close();

        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thanks a lot, on a non-SSL connection, I now get a nice orderly connection shutdown without a reset.

BUT apparently this method is not supported by `SSLSocket`? When I try it in my SSL client, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The method shutdownOutput() is not supported in SSLSocket
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.shutdownOutput(Unknown Source)
    at Security.SSLClientThread.run(SSLDemoClient.java:99)
```

My new code looks like this:

```
package Security;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class SSLDemoClient
{
    private static InetAddress host;
    private static Socket socket;
    private static final int PORT = 1234;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "key.keystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "vwpolo");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "key.keystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "vwpolo");

        System.out.println("\nCreating SSL socket ...");

        try
        {
            host = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.56.101");
            SocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            socket = socketFactory.createSocket(host, PORT);
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException uhEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nHost ID not found!\n");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(SSLException sslEx)
        {
            System.out.println("\nHandshaking unsuccessful ...");
            System.exit(1);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("\nHandshaking succeeded ...\n");

        SSLClientThread client = new SSLClientThread(socket);
        SSLReceiverThread receiver = new SSLReceiverThread(socket);

        client.start();
        receiver.start();

        try
        {
            client.join();
            receiver.join();
            System.out.println("Trying to close...");

            socket.close();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException iEx)
        {
            iEx.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("\nClient finished.");
    }
}


class SSLClientThread extends Thread
{
    private Socket socket;

    public SSLClientThread(Socket s)
    {
        socket = s;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            for( int i = 1; i < 1025; i++)
            {
                output.writeInt(i);
                sleep(10);
                output.flush();
            } 

            output.flush();
            sleep(1000);
            socket.shutdownOutput();
        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            System.out.println("Socket closed or unable to open socket.");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException iEx)
        {
            iEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


class SSLReceiverThread extends Thread
{
    private Socket socket;

    public SSLReceiverThread(Socket s)
    {
        socket = s;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String response = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;

        try
        {
            input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            try
            {
                response = input.readLine();
                while(!response.equals(null)) 
                {
                    System.out.print(response + " ");
                    response = input.readLine();
                } 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("\nEnd of server data.\n");
            }    

            socket.shutdownInput();

        }
        catch(IOException ioEx)
        {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I not using it correcty? Or is my SSLSocket not correct? Because with a non-SSL connection there is no problem.

Comment: I know this is an already (correctly) answered question, but I just want to point out to anyone coming across this question, that this behaviour is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/articles/connection_release.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your packet log shows that the client is sending its last bit of data, and notifying the server of the connection closing.

The server then sends back *its* last bit of data (the last converted integer, presumably).  The client responds with a `RST`, which indicates that the client socket was closed for both reading *and* writing - the client is saying "sorry, I didn't catch that last bit of data, I'm not listening anymore".

I am not a Java guru, but it appears that calling the `.close()` method of the socket's `OutputStream` is resulting in the `.close()` method being called on the socket itself.  What you actually want to happen here (after the client has written its last integer) is that the `shutdownOutput()` method is called on the socket.

Comment: That indeed fixed my problem on a non-SSL connection, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As caf points out, your problem is that you are calling `close` when you should be calling `shutdownOutput`.  This is because what you are trying to implement is what's called a half-close, in which each side of the connection closes it's output stream in order to indicate to the peer that there is no more data pending ( EOF ).

For an explanation of the difference between close and shutdown see this short SO answer "[close vs. shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409783/socket-shutdown-vs-socket-close/598759#598759)" and this longer article, "[Socket shutdown versus socket close](http://jython.xhaus.com/socket-shutdown-versus-socket-close-on-cpython-jython-and-java/)".  Also see, [Orderly Versus Abortive Connection Release in Java](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/articles/connection_release.html).

Answer (score 0):

The *real* problem here is that one end is writing after the other end has already closed its end of the connection. This is an application protocol error.