# Any cases Where close() is preferred to shutdown()?

Tags: c, sockets, shutdown

I am a developer on an open source project and I have been having some problems with the server thinking it has answered a socket completely (meaning it has either sent a reply or closed it's end in response to a failure) and the client being stuck in poll(). After some research, I found that close() doesn't always generate a POLLHUP event, but shutdown(sock, 2) does.

In light of that, I'm considering adding a shutdown(sock,2) in the event of error handling (in addition to the close() call). Does anyone know of some reasons that this would cause problems? Am I barking up the wrong tree? I'm thinking that if the server believes that the socket is closed, the client should definitely not attempt anything else with that socket, and I can't think of a reason not to add this, but I haven't been working with tcp connections for that long and would love some advice.

Comment: I would recommend this read:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409783/socket-shutdown-vs-socket-close

Comment: brain, that is an interesting read but it doesn't give me any reasons I wouldn't want to call shutdown in conjunction with close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to figure out why `close`ing the socket isn't causing it to `shutdown`. The most likely reason is that there is another descriptor that accesses the same endpoint. Only `close`ing the last endpoint causes an implicit `shutdown`.

Do you ever `dup` the file descriptor? Do you make sure it is `close`d in all child processes? If the socket was in a parent process before it `fork`ed this process, did the parent close their copy?

Comment: David, thanks for the advice. I have a feeling that the problem lies in tracking down what you said. I believe I have removed all forks from the code in favor of threads, but I will check into dups. One question though - does a close() always cause a shutdown when it is closed properly?

Comment: A close causes an implicit shutdown if closes the last descriptor that references that endpoint. The behavior of an implicit shutdown depends on the 'linger on close' settings.

Comment: `close` does not return error information. It therefore is almost never a substitute for `shutdown`. You don't know whether what you sent has been received.

Answer (score 0):

`POLLHUP` is not the right way to test for a closed connection. You should be testing for the file descriptor becoming readable and subsequently returning a zero-length read. This is the definition of end-of-file.

Comment: R, the code is using poll() with the set: pollset.events = POLLIN | POLLHUP; For reasons beyond my control, I can't change it from the poll() model. Either way, the client is blocking on that poll until timeout happens.

Comment: Yes, then check for `POLLIN`. EOF is a zero-length read that shows up as input available for read.

Comment: -1 `POLLHUP` IS the right way to check on some systems (MacOS comes to mind); the POSIX spec allows either.  So you really need to check for `POLLHUP|POLLIN` if you want to be portable.

Comment: @Chris: Citation? Even if you were right, I'm pretty sure this answer solves the problem OP encountered.

Comment: The code does check for POLLIN and POLLHUP (sorry I accidentally posted and then had to edit) but my problem persists.

Comment: It has happened on multiple versions of ubuntu.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on the operations the client and server are performing. Showing either some code or `strace` of the last few syscalls leading up the the client hanging and not realizing the server closed the connection would probably be sufficient.