# Gracefully stop socket during blocking call to socket.recv()

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have a program which runs on 2 threads. The main thread is for its own work and the other thread keeps calling `recv()` on a UDP socket.

Basically, the code structure looks like this:

```py
done = False

def run_sock():
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
   sock.bind(('localhost', 12345))
   while not done:  # receive data until work done
        data = sock.recv(1500)
        print(data)
   sock.close()

thread = threading.Thread(target=run_sock, daemon=True)
thread.start()

# Main thread
while not done:
    ... # Do work here
    if some_condition:  # Stop running, thread should as well
        done = True

thread.join()
```

I want to close the socket when the main thread changes `done` to `True`, but when that happens, the socket is still in its current blocking `recv` call and it has to receive another message before it finally stops.

Is there a way to gracefully close the socket (without having to handle errors)? I've tried `sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)`, `sock.setblocking(False)` and but they all raise errors.

Comment: miiiiight want to use a mutex or similar threadsafe structure to communicate between threads

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409783/socket-shutdown-vs-socket-close

Comment: @Will this is just an overly simplified version of what I'm currently working on. I don't want any redundant code because I don't think thread safety is the issue here

Comment: sock.recv(1500) should block forever if it doesn't get data so `done` is never checked and sock.close() never called

Comment: Yes, that's what my question is about.

Answer (score 0):

So `sock.recv(1500)` will block until it receives *something*. If it receives nothing, then it waits.

But if you set a timeout then periodically that wait will throw an exception and you can do other stuff (like look at the done flag) before trying to read again.

```
sock.settimeout(1.0)
sock.bind(...)

while not done:
    try:
        data = sock.recv(1500)
    except timeout:
        continue
sock.close()
```

Of course, if the remote end closes the connection that is different. Then you need to look at `data` to see if it is empty.

```
while not done:
    try:
        data = sock.recv(1500)
        if not data:
            break
    except timeout:
        continue
```