# What will happen to the socket if select timeout

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, epoll

On the basis of [shutdown vs close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409783/socket-shutdown-vs-socket-close) I have known the difference between shutdown and close.

But which will choose if select timeout in socket, the client will close or shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR).

I try to read the source code of select.c, but it is too hard to read.

Can anyone give me some help.

Comment: Neither. If `select()` times out, bothing has happened on the socket at all. No reason to either close or shut it down, unless you are concerned with inactivity timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But which will choose if select timeout in socket, the client will close or shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR).

If the client has a call to `select()`, the client can decide what to do when that call times out.

Almost by definition, if your `select()` times out, it's telling you that *nothing* happened to the socket (nothing that you told `select()` you were interested in, anyway).

Sockets don't automatically close (or shutdown) just because nothing happened for a while. You have to do that yourself, if you want it.

Comment: Yes, you are right。 I confuse timeout and shutdown, Thank you very much.